# Load list of array via an in web-browser

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome, browser, puppeteer

I need to load URL from multiple array in browser

So for example-: api url is `www.example.com/dst=ad`. Here `ad` is one set of input and I have number of list that needs to be executed one after another like 5-10 secs time interval.

I'm familiar with doing this via bash using for loop this kind of tasks but I needed to get this particular task only via browser.

so here is exactly what I needed

```
for dst in ad ef gh mn; do www.example.com/dst=$dst; done;
```

I wanted the browser to load the set of given lists for the api url one after another in browser as API gets authentication with signal signon. I heard this can be done via javascript but I'm not familiar with this language.

Can someone please provide any input with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
 const loadURL = async (interval, array) => {
    array.forEach(async (element) => {
      await fetch(`https://www.example.com/dst=${element}`)
})

await setTimeout(() => loadURL(interval, array), interval)
    }
    
    loadURL(yourIntervalTime, yourArray);
```